# Converting an array of floats to an array of strings in scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert the array created by numpy.linspace(1,10,1) to an array od strings in a scientific notation. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements of the array, and convert them to strings one by one:

```
array = numpy.linspace(1, 10, 1)
["%e" % x for x in array]
```

Here `%e` renders the number in scientific notation. You can also use `%f` for a notation with decimal point, or `%g` for auto-choice between different representations.